# Drawing a straight line and finding neighbouring area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, line

I have a shapefile showing district boundaries, and the coordinates of cities. I need to:

1. Draw a line between two coordinates e.g. draw a line between the centre of London city and the centre of Manchester city.
2. Select the districts where the line intersects
3. Select the neighbouring districts (districts directly beside the districts in 2.)

How can I do this?

I am sorry I do not have any figures to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just doing this once, there is actually a "Select by Line" in the Tools toolbar. [image: select tool]

And then for #3, follow with a "Select by Location" using the districts as your target layer, the selected districts as your source layer, and a method like intersects or touches the boundary.